# Getting Windows hardware information from cmd or powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

How can I determine if a mic, webcam, and speaker are installed onto a Windows device using Powershell or cmd? I don’t need to manipulate these devices, just need to determine if they are present.

Comment: Start searching for information about PowerShell `Get-CimClass` then `Get-CimInstance`. There is much available on the net. Use CIM rather than WMI where possible. If you are stuck in the `cmd` world, look for `wmic`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Get-PnpDevice` command is probably what you're looking for.